# Suddenly getting INDEX OUT OF RANGE exception vb.net

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

my form has a dgvw and a textbox.When i click on any of the rows in the dgvw, i've coded the textbox to show the 3rd cell's value in it .The code is :

```
 txt1.text=dgvw1.currentrow.cells(2).value
```

this works fine...but when i use this code instead :

```
txt1.Text = dgvw1.SelectedRows(dgvw1.CurrentRow.Index).Cells(2).Value.ToString
```

it gives me the index out of range exception!! Why ?? I don't get it! If the first code works,the second one should work as well!Why is it throwing an exception?

Answer (score 1):

`SelectedRows` and `CurrentRow` are independent. `SelectedRows` might not have any rows in it, it only contains the highlighted (blue) rows. `CurrentRow` is where the cursor is. This could be inside or outside the selection.

`DataGridView.CurrentRow.Index` is an index into the `DataGridView.Rows` collection and shouldn't be used with `DataGridView.SelectedRows`. `DataGridView.SelectedRows` is a subset of `DataGridView.Rows`

Try:

```
txt1.Text = dgvw1.Rows(dgvw1.CurrentRow.Index).Cells(2).Value.ToString
```

Comment: one more thing...
is this code
    
  
  txt1.text=dgvw1.Rows(dgvw1.CurrentRow.Index).Cells(2).Value.ToString

and this code :

    txt1.text=dgvw1.currentrow.cells(2).value

mean the same?

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: Yes, `dgvw1.Rows(dgvw1.CurrentRow.Index)` means the same thing as `dgvw1.CurrentRow`

Comment: one more thing...i know current row and selected row are different ! But when i click a row,isn't it simple that it would become selected?

Comment: Yes sometimes but it depends what you are trying to do. You might be better off handling the `RowEnter` event. Or using `DataGridView.CurrentCell`

Comment: Also, IIRC, `SelectedRows` depends on the `SelectionMode` you have picked.

Comment: It's like this. If your datagridview has 100 rows and your current row is row 88. Then your datagridview's selected rows are from rows 1 -10. What would happen with datagridview.selectedrows(88)? Of course it would be out of range.

Comment: If multi-select is set to false you can use selected rows. TextBox1.Text = DataGridView1.SelectedRows(0).Cells(2).Value Otherwise you would need to loop through a multiselect.

Comment: "*But when i click a row,isn't it simple that it would become selected?*" -- 
@AousafRashid Yes, *if* you've set `DataGridView.SelectionMode` to [`FullRowSelect`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3c89df86(v=vs.110).aspx#Members) or clicked the row header cell. Otherwise, no - clicking an ordinary cell does not select the row.